# Debugger don't receive breakpoint event

Tags: c++, windows, debugging

I am learning making a memory patch using visual c++ on VS2015 & windows10. So I 'CreateProcess' with DEBUG_PROCESS | DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS.
Then I get CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT soon, where I write 0xcc to the point I wanna break. After that, the debug target just hanging there and 'WaitForDebugEvent' cannot get me any debug event.
I dump the target and the INT3 do exist as it should be, run the dump file and it execute as it should do.
Here is the code:

```
    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
HANDLE PatchProcess;
BYTE ReadBuffer[MAX_PATH] = { 0 };
BYTE int3Code[1] = { 0xcc };
BYTE dwOldStyle[4] = { 0x65,0x65,0x65,0x65 };
if (!CreateProcess(FILE_NAME, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, DEBUG_PROCESS | DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
    std::cout << "CreateProcess failed" << std::endl;
    return false;
}
GetLastError();
PatchProcess = pi.hProcess;
DEBUG_EVENT dbEvent;
CONTEXT Regs;
DWORD dwState, Oldpp;

Regs.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL | CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS;
BOOL WhileDoFlag = true;
while (WhileDoFlag) {
    WaitForDebugEvent(&dbEvent, INFINITE);
    std::cout << "Waiting" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Debug event code:" << dbEvent.dwDebugEventCode << std::endl;
    dwState = DBG_EXCEPTION_HANDLED;
    switch (dbEvent.dwDebugEventCode)
    {
    case CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT:
        ReadProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, (LPVOID)(BP), &ReadBuffer, 2, NULL);
        GetLastError();
        std::cout << "Code at" << BP << ":" << ReadBuffer[0] << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        VirtualProtectEx(pi.hProcess, (LPVOID)BP, 4, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &Oldpp);
        GetLastError();
        WriteProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, (LPVOID)(BP), &int3Code, 2, NULL);
        GetLastError();
        dwState = DBG_CONTINUE;
        break;

    case EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT:
        WhileDoFlag = false;
        break;

    case EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT:
        switch (dbEvent.u.Exception.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionCode)
        {
            case EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT: 
            {
                GetThreadContext(pi.hThread, &Regs);
                if (Regs.Eip == BP + 1) {
                    Regs.Eip--;
                    WriteProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, (LPVOID)BP, &dwOldStyle, 4, 0);
                    GetLastError();
                    ReadProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, (LPVOID)(Regs.Ebp), &ReadBuffer, 1, 0);
                    GetLastError();
                    MessageBox(0, (char*)ReadBuffer, "patch test", MB_OK);
                    SetThreadContext(pi.hThread, &Regs);
                }
                dwState = DBG_CONTINUE;
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    ContinueDebugEvent(pi.dwProcessId, pi.dwThreadId, dwState);
}
```

Is it some kind of secure protection on Windows(after XP)?

PS:IDA can get the Breakpoint at the right place from the dump file with default local win32 debugger.
PS2:Using ollydbg to debug the dump file, the target crashed when execute

```
mov dword ptr ss:[esp+0x4],eax
```

eax is a ModuleEntryPoint
esp+0x4 is also a ModuleEntryPoint
Is it a bad breakpoint I add that caused the problem?

Comment: Isn't it too late to put the breakpoint there by the time `CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT` fires? On any modern CPU, you need to use `FlushInstructionCache` to make sure the CPU actually gets around to executing your breakpoint (it likely already has the code in instruction cache by that point). Also, why aren't you using `lpStartAddress`?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I add 'FlushInstructionCache' after WriteProcessMemory but nothing changed.It seems that the WriteProcessMemory will do a flush itself[from google] Maybe I didn't use it correctly.Then I discovered that the target code did't run at all.

Comment: I think you need to restore the original instruction and dereference the address to continue execution

Comment: Also you are writing two bytes, but your opcode is one byte.

Answer (score 0):

0xCC is one byte, you're writing 2 bytes causing the target process to crash, one of the bytes you're writing is just random garbage.  Only write the one byte in your call to `WriteProcessMemory()`